# How to tell scrapy to stop to crawl next page when meeting an empty page?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm new to scrapy. Basically, I have some web pages with the identical structure to crawl. Each web page is loaded dynamically when scrolling down, and the ajax request is in the format of `"https://example.org/ajax/unique_id_for_this_page/page=1/...."`. When reaching the end of the page, something in the response of ajax request is empty, so I can stop to send the next ajax request. How can I achieve this goal with scrapy? Here is the code I use.

```
class WebSpider(Spider):

    base_url = 'https://example.org/ajax/{}/page={}/...'

    def start_requests(self):

        # unique_id for different web pages required to crawl
        unique_ids = ['webpage01', 'webpage02', 'webpage03', ...]

        urls = [base_url.format(unique_id, 1) for unique_id in unique_ids]

        for url in urls:
            # send the 1st page's ajax requests of 3 web pages required to crawl
            yield Requests(url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        # parse the response and decide if sending the next ajax request
        res = json.loads(response.text)

        if res['data']['list']:
            # the list is not empty, save results and go to next
            save_results_to_item()

            current_page_num = re.search(r'page=(\d+)', response.url).group(1)
            next_page_num = int(current_page_num) + 1

            # generate the next ajax request
            next_page_url = response.url.replace(f'page={current_page_num}', f'page={next_page_num}')

            yield Requests(next_page_url, self.parse)
```

Will the code above be able to crawl all web pages and stop sending new ajax requests for the certain web page when `res['data']['list']` is empty? I find it difficult to figure out whether it worked. Or is there any better solution? Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Looks good to me. BTW you can use 'res = response.json()' instead.